# Avoid flash upload 30 seconds timeout when doing imagemagic convert?

Tags: php, flash, imagemagick

I have a web app that uses a flash uploader (swfuploader) and recently a user pointed us to a bug that happens when the script hangs more than 30 seconds.

I know flash documentation mentions that after 30 seconds of no response it will timeout, so i know i need to send some data to the browser before my convert function ends.

As of now the script uploads the file, convert it, and if it is a multipage pdf it will save the reference children pngs to db, this works fine on big and small files, problem happens that after 30 pages it will hang for more than 30 seconds.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should just build the whole thing to be asynch and then you dont have to worry about that... right?

Answer (score 2):

Either what Mark Robbins suggested, or you may be looking for this http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php , but you would also need to check the server settings (they might also limit the time the script is allowed to run).

Making PHP work asynchronously would be quite a task... I'm not saying this will be a perfect solution, but, it is the easiest to implement (at least so it seems to me): you could have start the "convert" as a separate process, get it's pid and save that pid in the session / other place you know to be associated with the client, and then have the client poll the server to ask for the work completion. Once the process associated with the pid exits, the client would need to receive what was saved into the directory where imagemagic converted things.